# algebraic intersection number and Poincare duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, poincare-duality

I am trying to understand the algebraic intersection number in terms of Poincare dual and the cup product. This is:
Let $M$ be a compact oriented $m$-dimensional smooth manifold together with a boundary decomposition $\partial M = A\cup B$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be a complementary pair of submanifolds of $M$ with $\partial X\subset A$ and $\partial Y\subset B$. We denote by $i:X\rightarrow M$ and $j:Y\rightarrow M$ the obvious inclusion maps. Furthermore we denote by $\left[ X\right] \in H_k(X,\partial X)$ and $\left[ Y\right] \in H_{m-k}(Y,\partial Y)$ the fundamental classes of $X$ and $Y$. Finally denote by
$$PD_M:H_{m-k}(M,B)\rightarrow H^{k}(M,A)$$
the inverse of Poincare duality.
Then
$$X\cdot Y= \langle \text{PD}_M(i_\star(\left[ X\right] ))\cup \text{PD}_M(j_\star(\left[ Y\right] )),\left[ M\right] \rangle.$$

Now let $K,J\subset S^3$ be knots and let $F_K$ be some Seifert-surface of $K$ such that $F_K$ and $J$ are transverse. Then for $T:B^2\times K\rightarrow S^3$ an appropiate thickening and $M=X_K=S^3\setminus T(B^2\times K)$ we obtain

$$L\cdot F_K = \langle \underbrace{\text{PD}_{X_K}(j_\star(\left[ L\right] ))}_{\color{red}{=??}}\cup \text{PD}_{X_K}(i_\star(\left[ F^\prime\right] )),\left[ X_K\right] \rangle$$

As highlighted in red I want to figure out what the Poincare dual of $j_\star ([L])$ is.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Let's say we are working with field coefficients. Then a cohomology class is determined by how it evaluates on homology classes. Then the Poincare dual $[\beta] \in H^{m-k}(M,B)$ of $[\alpha] \in H_k(X,A)$ is such that for $[\sigma] \in H_{m-k}(M,B)$$\langle [\beta], [\sigma] \rangle$ is given by the oriented intersection number of $[\alpha]$ and $[\sigma]$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I want to proof that $L\cdot F_K=\text{lk}(L,K)$. I know if we replace $X_K$ with $S^3\setminus((B^2\times K) \cup(B^2\times L))$ we get this desired equality rather easily. But because of this it should be possible to say a lot more about $\text{PD}_{X_K}(j_\star([L])$ aswell and we should come to this equality the above way aswell.